# When exactly did Renly discover Joffrey is illegitimate?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In books? In series? I thought in either, it was because of Stannis' letters that he first came to know it (or if he didn't believe it: he was first came to be informed about about such possibility), but that doesn't seem to add up with Renly convincing Ned to kidnap Joffrey.

---

Related questions:

[What is Renly's basis for removing Joffrey?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110622/what-is-renlys-basis-for-removing-joffrey), [What was the basis for Lord Renly's claim to the throne?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50668/what-was-the-basis-for-lord-renlys-claim-to-the-throne), [Since Joffrey was a minor, why the urgency?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110378/since-joffrey-was-a-minor-why-the-urgency)

Comment: Renly was part of a plan to replace Cersei with Margaery Tyrell. Presumably such a plan was to work only after Cersei had been removed, as setting her aside would not be wise, with Tywin Lannister alive. As far as I recall, Stannis only told Jon Arryn about his suspicions.

Comment: @TLP cmiiw, but in both the books and series Stannis sent letters to the high lords of westeros?

Comment: He did, but only after Ned Stark was beheaded and Renly fled.

Comment: @TLP Wait did you myb mean 'Jon Arryn told only Stannis' ? Wait I don't get it. So Renly didn't know about Joffrey's illegitimacy when he wanted to remove him and Cersei? He wanted to remove them because he planned to take the throne for himself and Margaery Tyrell?

Answer (score 3):

In the books, immediately after Robert's death, Renly asked Ned Stark to support his claim to the throne, and to arrest Cersei's children. So he must have known about Joffrey's illegitimacy then.

Comment: how does this not apply to the series as well?

Comment: Maybe it does, I simply don't remember the details.

Comment: Renly did not ask him to arrest Cersei's children. He asked Ned to take them in his custody by saying "Whoever holds the King, holds the Kingdom". Which makes it clear that Renly did not know about Joff's parentage back then. For more detailed argument, [See my answer on Renly's ignorance about Joff's true parentage](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/138033/54887)